# count an average of multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was asked to count an average of a multidimensional array (table). I think that I build everything correctly (at least I feel so):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exam {
    static int NROWS = 5;
    static int NCOL = 6;
    static int[][] data = new int[NROWS][NCOL];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    enterData(scan);
    countAvg();
}

static void enterData(Scanner in) {
    System.out.println("How many rows ? (up to " + NROWS + ")");
    int rows = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many cols ? (up to " + NCOL + ")");
    int cols = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        System.out.println("Row" + i + ": ");
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            System.out.print("Enter Data for Column " + j + ":");
            data[i][j] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }
}

static void countAvg() {
    int total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NCOL; j++) {
            total = total + data[i][j];
            count = count++;
        }
    }
    int avg = total / count;
    System.out.println("the average is: " + avg);
}
```

}

but the system still pushes me this message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
>       at Exam.countAvg(Exam.java:33)
>       at Exam.main(Exam.java:9)

Please help me to understand what am I doing wrong. Many thanks!

Comment: It says you are dividing by 0. I would think this would be on the line `int avg = total / count;` So, your count is 0 here. I don't know how `count = count++'` works, so just try doing `count++`

Comment: Yeah. That definitely is your problem. I've tested it. Take out `count =` and just use `count++;`

Comment: Thank you, Michael! Now for some reason, the average counts as 0 what is incorrect. What do you think, where can be a hidden issue?

Comment: It is because you are doing integer divison which drops off the decimals. Change `int avg` to `double avg = total / (double) count;`

Comment: Im going to add an answer and I've found something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change `count = count++;` to just `count++;`

Second, you are doing integer division, so change `int avg = total/count;` to `double int = total / (double) count;`

Third, you are setting your data array as 5X6, even if they input something different, this will throw off the average as count will add for every cell, 30 in all.

Instead, try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exam {
    static int[][] data;
    private static int rows = 0;
    private static int cols = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        enterData(scan);
        countAvg();
    }

    static void enterData(Scanner in) {
        System.out.println("How many rows ?");
        rows = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many cols ?");
        cols = in.nextInt();
        data = new int[rows][cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            System.out.println("Row" + i + ": ");
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                System.out.print("Enter Data for Column " + j + ":");
                data[i][j] = in.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    static void countAvg() {
        int total = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                total = total + data[i][j];
                count++;
            }
        }
        double avg = total / (double) count;
        System.out.println(count + "the average is: " + avg);
    }
}
```

This will allow you to create a new data array with the input rows and cols, which allows you to calculate the average correctly.

Comment: thank you! I was thinking the same about ROWS and COLS but those static variables are the part of the default  package which was offered for changes.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Pickett mentioned in above comments, Issue is with the `count = count++;`. All ways your count becomes zero because you are using `post-increment`, so the incrementing is happening after the line executed.If you use `pre-increment` `count = ++count;` incrementing is happening while executing the line.

So you can you can use `pre-increment` as above or `post-increment` without assigning it to `count` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Alongside the other answers (both correct) note a couple of things that might improve the readability of your code. You can use a 'for-each' loop instead of using indices and you can use `+=` for adding the value to the total:

```
for (int[] row: data) {
    for (int value: row) {
        total += value;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Also note, if you are familiar with Java 8, you can do this in a single statement:

```
Arrays.stream(data).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).average()
```

This returns an `OptionalDouble` to allow for the possibility of the array being empty (by returning an `Optional.empty`)